# Separate string into balanced substrings with equal numbers of R and L characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, loops

As a homework, I need to write a program that keeps prompting the user for a balanced string until getting a valid input. For the purpose of this program, a balanced string is defined as having a non-zero, equal number of characters 'R' (capital) and characters 'L'(capital), regardless of the presence of other characters.

The program then separates/divides the balanced input string into as many balanced substrings as possible and generates a list of them

For example:

Input:

```
Please enter a string containing an equal number or 'R' and 'L': RLRLRLRLRLab
```

Output:

```
['RL', 'RL', 'RL', 'RL', 'RLab']
```

I'm really confused on how to implement this code. I know how to find if R or L are present in the input, but that's about it. I don't need the whole code, just a starting point.

Comment: `["RL" + i for i in s.split("RL")]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point for an algorithm that should solve this problem:

- Maintain a variable `balance` that is initialized with 0
- Create an empty string `temp`
- Iterate over every character in the input string:

  - If the character is `R` increase `balance` by 1
  - If the character is `L` decrease `balance` by 1
  - Append the character to `temp`
  - If `balance` is 0 and `temp` contains any `L` or `R` character, add `temp` to the result list and reset it to an empty string

There might be some corner cases for which you should tweak or extend this algorithm. For example, handling the remaining characters at the end of the input string.